# Table width stretches beyond 100% on setting position to fixed

Tags: html, css

My table has 2 header rows and 50 body rows. It has 20 columns.
I need to show the table within the page width(table shouldn't go beyond 100% width), so that the user does not have to scroll to right, i.e. **no horizontal scrollbar** should appear.
When vertical scrolling the **header rows has to be kept fixed**.
The table columns are of different width.

This is what I've done till now.

- Created 2 tables. All header portion in one table, and the body portion in another table.
- The table layout is "fixed", as I have to set different column widths.
  Both the table widths I have set to 100%.
- The scrollbar was causing issues to the upper table(tab1), so I forced the vertical scrollbar on the page. This is not a problem, because the content goes beyond the screen height anyway.

When I set **`position: fixed`** for upper table, it causes alignment problems between the two tables. 
The position: fixed  property makes the upper table go beyond 100%.

If I set the upper table width as 99%, it appears fine for some resolutions screens, but for others (higher than 1600 X 900 ), it's again misaligned.

Below is my code.

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#tab1 {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: fixed;
}
#tab2 {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tab1">
  <caption>Test Report Dt - 12/12/2016</caption>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:130px;">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <col style="width:180px;">
    <col style="width:100px;">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:90px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:90px; ">
    <col style="width:120px;">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="7">BAT Tool</th>
    <th colspan="7">ACT Tool</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Project Name</th>
    <th>Build Version</th>
    <th>Test Owner</th>
    <th>Test Date DD-MMM-YY</th>
    <th>TC Executed</th>
    <th>Passed Count</th>
    <th>Failed Count</th>
    <th>Pass %</th>
    <th>Fail %</th>
    <th>Automation % coverage</th>
    <th>Remarks</th>
    <th>TC Executed</th>
    <th>Passed Count</th>
    <th>Failed Count</th>
    <th>Hold Count</th>
    <th>Pass %</th>
    <th>Fail%</th>
    <th>Remark</th>
    <th>Other Remarks</th>
    <th>BAT Report Link</th>
    <th>ACT Report Link</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="tab2">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:130px;">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <col style="width:180px;">
    <col style="width:100px;">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:90px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:90px; ">
    <col style="width:120px;">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Project 1</td>
    <td>v 1.1</td>
    <td>Daniel Ruth , d.ruth, 1234</td>
    <td>12-Dec-16</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>100%</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Remark1</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>91.8%</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a target='_blank' href='http://sample1.html'>Link</a></td>
    <td><a target='_blank' href='http://sample2.html'>Link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that is a pretty intense structure. What is the point of that many nested `col` elements? Imo, that is half of your problem right there.

Second, you can't give one table a bunch of columns and expect it to fit the screen width at all resolutions. This is akin to trying to violate basic laws of physics; there's a finite amount of space, you can't expect it to accommodate such a wide table.

Comment: That is to specify the individual column widths. And Those are not nested. Those are inside <colgroup>. I'll edit the question.

Comment: It's still pretty wild man, you just have too much content stacked horizontally.

Comment: That is my requirement, how can I represent the same info in a different layout.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#tab1, #tab2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tab1">
    <caption> Test Report  Dt - 12/12/2016</caption>
    <col style="width:130px;">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <col style="width:180px;">
    <col style="width:100px;">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:90px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:90px; ">
    <col style="width:120px;">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <col style="width:70px; ">

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="7">BAT Tool</th>
        <th colspan="7">ACT Tool</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Build Version</th>
        <th>Test Owner</th>
        <th>Test Date DD-MMM-YY</th>
        <th>TC Executed</th>
        <th>Passed Count</th>
        <th>Failed Count</th>
        <th>Pass %</th>
        <th>Fail %</th>
        <th>Automation % coverage</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>TC Executed</th>
        <th>Passed Count</th>
        <th>Failed Count</th>
        <th>Hold Count</th>
        <th>Pass %</th>
        <th>Fail%</th>
        <th>Remark</th>
        <th>Other Remarks</th>
        <th>BAT Report Link</th>
        <th>ACT Report Link</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="tab2">

    <col style="width:130px;">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <col style="width:180px;">
    <col style="width:100px;">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:90px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:50px; ">
    <col style="width:90px; ">
    <col style="width:120px;">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <col style="width:70px; ">
    <tr>
        <td>Project 1</td>
        <td>v 1.1</td>
        <td>Daniel Ruth , d.ruth, 1234</td>
        <td>12-Dec-16</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>100%</td>
        <td>0%</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Remark1</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>91.8%</td>
        <td>0%</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a target='_blank' href='http://sample1.html'>Link</a></td>
        <td><a target='_blank' href='http://sample2.html'>Link</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This does not help. If I change the position type of first table from "fixed" to "relative", the header does not get fixed in the place. I need to keep the header row fixed when scrolling.